# UITableView empty with background call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have the following issue which I googled and been playing to some extent.
I have a tableView, I can add objects to it and populate it correctly, but when I replace a backend call (goes through external library so quite keen on keeping it simple) the table is coming out empty. I can see that the call is made after it is rendered so wondering if you can help.

```
    class FindBuddiesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    var users:[AppUser] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

       //populates the array users from Firebase
        users = DBHelper.getAllRelatedUsersForVid("1234")
        populateTable(users)


    }

    func populateTable(users: [AppUser]) -> Void {
        for element in users {
            let appUser: AppUser = AppUser(id: element.id, displayName: element.displayName, email: element.email, profileImageURL: element.profileImageURL, following: element.following, follower: element.follower)
            print(appUser.displayName)
            self.objects.addObject(appUser)
            print("count of dbusers: \(users.count)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            doTableRefresh()
        }

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.objects.count
    }

    func doTableRefresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let user = self.objects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! AppUser
        cell.titleLabel.text = user.displayName
        cell.followButton.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row+1 == objects.count {
            print("came to last row")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showView", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func logAction(sender:UIButton)
    {
        let titleString = self.objects.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as? String
        let firstActivityItem = "\(titleString)"
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

The static method looks like this
    static func getAllRelatedUsersForVid(vid: String!) -> [AppUser]
    {
        var users = AppUser

```
    // Get a reference to our posts
    let ref = Firebase(url:"https://firebaseProject.firebaseio.com/users")
    // Attach a closure to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot 

            let appUser: AppUser = AppUser(id: String(rest.value.valueForKey("uid")), displayName: String(rest.value.valueForKey("displayName")), email: String(rest.value.valueForKey("email")), profileImageURL: String(rest.value.valueForKey("profileImageURL")), following: false, follower: false)
            users.append(appUser)
            print("finished user count \(users.count)")

        }

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })

           return users
}
```

So if I manually created the user objects and appended it to objects it would work absolutely fine and I would see them on the tableView. But when I add the call it does not. Any ideas why this is? How can I get for the tableView to wait for the call. Keep in mind that I cannot change this line users = DBHelper.getAllRelatedUsersForVid("1234") which is a static method on DBHelper. An example would be much appreciated as have been playing with this for sometime with no real luck.

Comment: You posted a bunch of code. What backend call are you talking about? Direct us to the line of code and tell us how it reads when it works vs. when it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `getAllRelatedUsersForVid` ?

Comment: Are you talking about the function `DBHelper.getAllRelatedUsersForVid`? Is that fetching data from a network? Or is it an async call? Usually async APIs have a method for you to be notified once they're done: Either you set yourself as the delegate, or provide a completion block that gets called once the operation is complete.

Comment: @user2091936 Don't post code in comments. Edit your original question.

Comment: Updated code to ensure it has getAllRelatedUsersForVid as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `getAllRelatedUsersForVid`. As it is right now, it will always return an empty `users` array, that's why it's not showing anything. This call is async so you need to use a closure to call back once the Firebase call is fired.

I'd recommend passing the closure back like this:

```
func getAllRelatedUsersForVid(string: String, completion: [AppUser] -> Void) {
    ...
    // This is async
    let ref = Firebase(url:"https://firebaseProject.firebaseio.com/users")
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot

        let appUser: AppUser = AppUser(id: String(rest.value.valueForKey("uid")), displayName: String(rest.value.valueForKey("displayName")), email: String(rest.value.valueForKey("email")), profileImageURL: String(rest.value.valueForKey("profileImageURL")), following: false, follower: false)
        users.append(appUser)

        // Call completion
        completion(users)
    }
    ...

}
```

And your viewDidLoad will looks something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    DBHelper.getAllRelatedUsersForVid("1234") { users in
        populateTable(users)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, you were right! That definitely solved it. Many thanks.